# Need to call c library from java

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface

I have developed a JAVA GUI in Swing. It will take an input file path from the user and send it to native code (C Library).

C functions will do lot of analysis and store the results in buffered locations. My requirement is to call native code from Java and fill the Swing GUI components (Tables, Trees, etc) with that analyzed data.

I have gone through JNI but I don't understand it. Please suggest on this (better documentation on JNI or any other solution).

Comment: Vist [JNI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/), when you have a specific problem, go back and do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: A slightly more convenient mechanism is to use JNA, which is a lot easier to work with. https://github.com/twall/jna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI is probably the way to go, maybe you just need a simpler example.
Try this: https://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/a_simple_example_of_jni